# Custom PHP extension security

Tags: php, security

I would like to create a PHP extension to do some specific crystallographic functionality.

1. Is it possible for an attacker to disassemble (or somehow xdebug) the extension to find out how it works?
2. Could the attacker find out constants or variables which are set inside of the extension (for inst. a password, salt, etc...)?

**UPDATE**

The idea was:

- I want to store some data in DB encrypted, I also want to make sure that every user has his own password/salt, so nobody could access data of somebody else in case the attacker would find a hole in the access control.
- I could to the encryption in PHP. But if somebody gains the access to the web directory, he can easily see how I do that... he can just take the data and decrypt it at home.
- I could make the extension. The attacker would need gain access to the whole filesystem to get the extension. I could limit the extension use just for the server's IP address (so the attacker would not be able to take the data out from the server that easily). Wouldn't it be more secure? Is there some other way how to do it better?

Comment: Somehow I feel like this extension doesn't deal with "the branch of science concerned with the structure and properties of crystals."

Comment: Try it yourself! You're the best hacker there can be! You know the code so try to hack it :D

Comment: Yes and yes. If not already statically using a disassembler, at last dynamically with a debugger.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. yes. Your file is on a machine controlled by the "attacker". You need permanent, perfect security. They just have to find one minor little hole. What you want is impossible, and will always remain so.

Comment: Extensions can be debugged using tools like gdb, so any internal information is accessible if the user has access to a machine where your extension is running

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to secure the workings of your [Crystallography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallography) extension so much?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for an attacker to disassemble the extension to find out how it works

Yes. This is pretty trivial to get code back out. The variable names will be stripped (assuming it's a non-debug build), but it's 100% possible to get the code.

> Could the attacker find out constants or variables which are set inside of the extension (for inst. a password, salt, etc...)?

Yes, these are always stored in the file in plain text. In fact, there's a unix command `strings` which will extract it for you.

A better solution would be to look at the problem you're trying to solve, figure out what attack vectors you want to protect against, and then mitigating them. There is no magic solution to any of it.